# How to find if SQL Server 2008 Management Objects installed?

Tags: sql-server-2008, smo

My application needs SMO libraries to be installed. I want my installer to verify if SQL Server 2008 Management Objects already installed and if not install the SMO feature pack bundled with my installer. How do I find out if it is already installed? Is there any registry key to verify?

Thanks,
Hem

Comment: Can someone reply this, please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution for SQL Server 2012:

```
HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\SharedManagementObjects\CurrentVersion\Version
```

You can check if this key exists (and check if the value is greater than 11).

Answer (score 0):

I think the registry key for SMO is located at `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Database`.  You could probably check to see if this key exists and install the Feature Pack if it's not there.  Take a look [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-IE/sqlsetupandupgrade/thread/5e18ef08-92cd-4c49-a103-14a5b717a3f4) and see if it helps you?